# not able to mention data text field in autocomplete extender

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I am using this [kendo ui autocomplete widget](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/autocomplete/overview) for textbox by using the following method in controller:

```
public ActionResult GetItems(string term)
{
    ContextObject contextObject = new ContextObject();
    TransactionHistory transactionhistory = new TransactionHistory();
    var items = transactionhistory.GetItems(contextObject, term);
    // the above method will gives list of strings
    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                     
}
```

and this is my view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
      .Name("ItemSearch")
      .DataTextField("RPersonDetails")
      .DataSource(source => {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetItems", "TransactionHistoryResults")
                  .Data("onAdditionalData");
          })
          .ServerFiltering(true);              
      })
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100px" })
)

<script type="text/javascript">
   function onAdditionalData() {
        return {
            text: $("#ItemSearch").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

In the link we have got **datatextfield** that is for Specifying  which property of the Product(table) to be used by the autocomplete and in my scenario this method `transactionhistory.GetItems(contextObject, term);` is giving list of strings, so in that case what I need to mention in this field `DataTextField("RPersonDetails")` in place of `RPersonDetails`.

Do I need to change the GetItems method?  Please give any suggestions and ideas on this one.... 
Many thanks In advance....

Comment: If your result set is just a list of strings maybe you don't need to specify the `DataTextField`; try removing it.

Comment: Is `RPersonDetails` a property of `TransactionHistory`?

Comment: Did removing the `DataTextField` resolve the issue?

Comment: @asymptoticFault, yes.. How can we get the selected item back to the controller (in this wrapper approach)?

Comment: Great I'll post that as the answer then :)  The selected item should be posted back to the controller when you submit the form, or are you trying to send it back another way?

Comment: @asymptoticFault How can we get it in the controller since it is a ajax binding?

Comment: You should be able to get it back to the controller by generating another request with the value in it.  Values can be passed to the controller from the view via the route values (values extracted from your routes), the querystring or form values (i.e. input elements inside a form).

Comment: @asymptoticFault  I have done samples like creating property in model and defining textbox in view related to that property and getting textbox entered value into controller ..... so here I am not able to bind the model property to this textbox(autocomplete widget) how can i do that .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete workinng sample for kendo ui auto-complete and retrieving selected value in controller. It uses `hidden field` for setting the selected value.

controller

```
public class SampleController : Controller
    {


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult MyProducts()
        {
            List<string> myStrings = new List<string>();
            myStrings.Add("AA");
            myStrings.Add("AB");
            return Json(myStrings, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostValues(sampleModel model)
        {

            string temp = model.SelectedItem;
            return View("Index");

        }

    }
```

Model

```
public class sampleModel
    {
        public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
    }
```

VIEW

```
@model  MyNamespace.sampleModel

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using( @Html.BeginForm("PostValues","Sample" ))
{
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedItem)


@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
      .Name("productAutoComplete")
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
              source.Read(read =>
             {
                 read.Action("MyProducts", "Sample")
                          .Data("onAdditionalData");
             });
      }
      )
      .Events(e => e
        .Select("autocomplete_select")
        .Change("autocomplete_change")
    )

)

<input id="Button1" type="submit" value="PostValues" />
}
<script>
    function onAdditionalData() {
        return {
            text: $("#productAutoComplete").val()
        };
    }

    function autocomplete_select()
    {

    }

    function autocomplete_change() {
        $('#SelectedItem').val($("#productAutoComplete").val());
        alert($('#SelectedItem').val());
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Server Filtering refer to the following:

```
public JsonResult MyProducts(string text)
{
    List<string> myStrings = new List<string>();
    myStrings.Add("Aa");
    myStrings.Add("ACB");
    myStrings.Add("cc");

    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var results = myStrings
        .Where<string>(item => regEx.IsMatch(item))
        .ToList<string>();

    return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

UI:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
    .Name("productAutoComplete")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("MyProducts", "Sample")
                .Data("onAdditionalData");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true); //If true the DataSource will not filter the data on the client.
    }
    )
    .Events(e => e
        .Select("autocomplete_select")
        .Change("autocomplete_change")
    )
)
```

Script:

```
function onAdditionalData() {
    return {
        text: $("#productAutoComplete").val()
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataTextField` method is for specifying the property of an object in the list.  If your result set is just a list of strings maybe you don't need to specify the DataTextField; try removing it.